# upload images in the database

Tags: image, upload

I have been trying to upload an image into the table but no joy at all.
I have used a store procedure and encrypted my connection strings in the appsettings and use data layer to access the objects.

```
        string FilePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        string ContentType = string.Empty;
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".jpg":
                ContentType = "Image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                ContentType = "Image/png";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                ContentType = "Image/gif";
                break;
        }
        if (ContentType != string.Empty)
        {
            Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

       SqlCommand _SqlCom = new SqlCommand("sp_InsFoto");
       _SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@imgName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
       _SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Imgdata", SqlDbType.Binary).Value =bytes;
       _SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@imgContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =ContentType;
       obj.ExecuteNonQuery(ref _SqlCom);
```

And I have the store procedure as stated below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsFoto]
(

     @ImgName varchar(50)
    ,@ImgData varbinary(MAX)
    ,@ImgContentType varchar(50)       
)

AS INSERT INTO tbl_Fotos
(
         ImgName
        ,ImgData
        ,ImgContentType   
)

VALUES
(   
         @ImgName
        ,@ImgData
        ,@ImgContentType    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**UPLOADING IMAGE AND SAVING PATH IN THE DATABASE
________________________________________________________________________________________
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
            <h3> Choose File to Upload in Server </h3>          
           <form action="Recent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
            </form>          
        </div>


</body>
</html>
____________________________________________________________________________________________

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.ParameterParser;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class Recent
 */
@WebServlet("/Recent")
@MultipartConfig
public class Recent extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Recent() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Sample  s1=new Sample();
         final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/home/pradeep/Documents/pradeep/WebContent/Images";
         if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
                try {
         List<FileItem> multiparts = new 
                            ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                    for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                        if(!item.isFormField())
                        {
                            String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                            item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                            String Path= "/home/pradeep/Documents/pradeep/WebContent/Images/" +name;


                          s1.connecting(Path);


                        }
                    }

                        request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                   request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
                }          

            }else{
                request.setAttribute("message",
                                     "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
            }



                request.getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(request, response);




    }

}
__________________________________________________________________________________________
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import dbconnections.Connections;



public class Sample {
    Connections con=new Connections();

    public void connecting(String Path)
    {
        Connection conn=con.Connect();

        PreparedStatement pst;
        String query="INSERT INTO Student1 (Path) values (?)";
       try {

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1,Path);
            pst.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

Comment: please don't copy the exact same answer to several questions - chances are that either they don't really fit all or the questions are duplicates (and should be flagged as such)

Answer (score 0):

Name of parameters in your code should exactly match names defined in stored procedure, so in the code below change `@imgName` to `@ImgName` and `@imgContentType` to `@ImgContentType`:

```
SqlCommand _SqlCom = new SqlCommand("sp_InsFoto");
_SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@imgName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
_SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Imgdata", SqlDbType.Binary).Value =bytes;
_SqlCom.Parameters.Add("@imgContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =ContentType;
obj.ExecuteNonQuery(ref _SqlCom);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I changed it as you said but no go.ImgName and ImgContentType gets stored but not the ImgData.Please let me know if there is anything to be done to store the images in the binary stream.